# Post data to angular 4 application

Tags: javascript, angular

I have an angular application which has a component which displays HTML form based on the JSON provided to it. The angular application is deployed on server. It doesn't have back-end code like in `node.js`. The angular app entirely dependent on WebAPI for data operations.

There is other desktop application which is going to launch browser, open angular application at `localhost:4200` and post the JSON data. How would I be able to access this data in my component?

Comment: use fiddler to use mock data

Answer (score 0):

I guess you cannot post data to angular application. if security doesn't matter you can pass data as url parameters or query strings

Comment: The JSON data could be very large at times.

Comment: If that the case I don't see any other way. Use could try JSON.stringify(data) post data and see the impact of loading.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot post data to an Angular application or at least I don't know how.

What you can do would be to pass to your application the url where the data you want to inject is hosted, then in your Angular application retrieves the URL inside a service by injecting in that service constructor `ActivatedRoute` which provides info about the current path.

From there, you can extract the URL (where the data is), and with HttpClient you can load data.

Next, you will have to push the data received from your provider asynchronously to your components. This can be done by using ReplaySubject (implementations of Subject) from rxJs (your components must subscribe to a stream of data which will be provided later), but this is another topic.